# Kafka connect with confluent avro couldn't find SchemaRegistryClient class

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, avro, confluent-schema-registry

Running jdk17, Apache Kafka 3.5.1, Connect distributed mode, properly set plugin path, with confluent avro plugins taken from: https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-avro-converter

The source connector is configured as:

```
{
    "connector.class": "...",
    "tasks.max": "3",
    "name": "test-connector",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "errors.log.enable": "true"
}
```

The plugins are confirmed being loaded during kafka connect startup log messages. The `kafka-schema-registry-client-7.5.0.jar` is confirmed present in the plugin dir.

But when the connector starts, its tasks fail with the same exception:

https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-avro-converter

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Instantiation error
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.newPlugin(Plugins.java:85)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.newConverter(Plugins.java:327)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startTask(Worker.java:622)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.startSourceTask(Worker.java:548)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startTask(DistributedHerder.java:1833)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.lambda$getTaskStartingCallable$32(DistributedHerder.java:1850)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/client/SchemaRegistryClient
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3373)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3578)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2754)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:396)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.newPlugin(Plugins.java:83)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.SchemaRegistryClient
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:592)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:136)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
        ... 15 more
```

Any idea on where the problem may be?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in windows <-> wsl2. I was moving files (jars, plugins, etc.) from windows to wsl via Explorer and that messed up things for some reason. Once i started moving files only within wsl, all problems were resolved.

Comment: If you use confluent-hub CLI, then files will be added in the correct locations